# dkim=temperror (no key for signature) then dkim=pass

Tags: dkim

I published a DKIM record for my niceoldteacher.com domain that is hosted by fatcow.com and sent an email to one of my gmail accounts to see if DKIM was working.  Although the header summary for the received email indicated that SPF, DKIM, and DMARC all passed, I found the following DKIM information in the detailed header and I was wondering about the significance of the dkim=temperror part and if it should be fixed somehow.  If so, what do I need to do to fix it?  I'm a complete novice at all of this authentication business.

```
ARC-Authentication-Results: i=1; mx.google.com;
   dkim=temperror (no key for signature) header.i=@kindoldteacher.com header.s=dkim header.b=2naFLU6D;
   dkim=pass header.i=@kindoldteacher.com header.s=1557715744.kindoldteacher header.b=OvYU6UvG;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Obviously your messages are get signed twice for some reason

The first erroneous header, that has not DNS pubkey record

`dkim=temperror (no key for signature) header.i=@kindoldteacher.com header.s=dkim header.b=2naFLU6D;`

And the second time

`dkim=pass header.i=@kindoldteacher.com header.s=1557715744.kindoldteacher header.b=OvYU6UvG;`

That latter DKIM-header is valid and everything is fine.

To fix the issue you should remove somehow the first DKIM header with selector `dkim`.

You should get rid of the ontopic error after that.